# Does the entanglement depend on the basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, tensor-calculus

Let's say, we have a composite system $A\otimes B$. We take the basis for $A$ as $|i\rangle,|j\rangle...,$ the basis for $B$ as $|\alpha\rangle,|\beta\rangle....$
Then an entangled state is a state which can not be expressed as a tensor direct product, e.g. a state like
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|i\ \alpha\rangle+|j\ \beta\rangle).$$
My question is, can a state which can not be expressed as a tensor direct product in one basis be expressed as a tensor direct product in another basis?

If yes, then it means that the entanglement depends on the basis which I think is hard to accept. If no, then there should be an invariant under the basis transformation to character the entanglement. What's that?

Comment: The most general tensor product looks like $\left(\lambda_i |i\rangle + \lambda_j |j\rangle + \lambda_k | k\rangle\right) \otimes \left( \mu_\alpha |\alpha\rangle + \mu_\beta |\beta\rangle +\mu_\gamma 
| \gamma \rangle \right)$. If you apply a change basis to $i,j,k$ and a different change of basis to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, it will still be of this form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is no: whether or not the state can be written as a product state does not depend on the basis.  And you are precisely correct: there is indeed a basis-independent invariant that characterizes the entanglement.  It is called the "entanglement spectrum": the eigenvalue spectrum of the reduced density matrix produced by taking the partial trace over one part of the system.  These are also called the "Schmidt weights" of the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition), which is another name for the singular value decomposition of the matrix that characterizes the entangled state vector.

To reduce the entanglement spectrum down to a single number that quantifies the amount of entanglement, one calculates the "entanglement entropy" corresponding to the entanglement spectrum.  There are several different types of entanglement entropies: the most common is the [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy), but sometimes it's also useful to consider the [Renyi entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) instead.

For example, the state $|\uparrow \uparrow \rangle + |\uparrow \downarrow \rangle + |\downarrow \uparrow \rangle + |\downarrow \downarrow \rangle$ might look entangled upon quick inspection, but by performing the Schmidt decomposition it's easy to see that the state equals $(|\uparrow \rangle + | \downarrow \rangle) \otimes (|\uparrow \rangle + | \downarrow \rangle)$ and is therefore an unentangled product state.

Answer (score 6):

No, the entanglement (yes/no) doesn't depend on the basis of the two subsystems, only on the way how the two subsystems are separated from one another.

A non-entangled state is a state of the form $|j\rangle \otimes |\alpha\rangle$ for some states $|j\rangle,|\alpha\rangle$ of the two subsystems; all other states in the composite Hilbert space are entangled. The previous statement clearly doesn't make any reference to any basis so it cannot depend on any choice of such a basis.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can use the entanglement entropy to calculate the amount of entanglement in a bipartite pure state, but this is not a good measure for a general bipartite (mixed) state. In the general case there are several different entanglement measures currently used, which have certain desiderata: https://quantiki.org/wiki/axiomatic-approach. Invariance under local operations then immediately implies invariance under basis changes.